# Function for the maximum index of vector in clojure

Tags: function, clojure

Hi I'd like to ask how to get the maximum value of index from Vector in clojure?

> (def dummyvector [190 260 300 310 250])

I have dummyvector here, index 0 = 190, 1 = 260 ... I know the maximum is index 4 = 250.
Does clojure have function to get the index value of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the list of documentation in [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template), especially Getting Clojure, Brave Clojure, and the Clojure CheatSheet.

As for your particular question, just type something like:

```
> (count [5 4 3 2 1])
5
```

You can then use the `dec` function (decrement by 1) to get `4`.

```
> (dec (count [5 4 3 2 1]))
4
```

If you are instead trying to search for an arbitrary value in the list, you may wish to use Java interop like:

```
(.indexOf  [0 2 4 1 3 5]  4) => 2
```

Comment: also wrap that in a dec to get the index  position:)

Answer (score 2):

Indexes are zero-based in Clojure so you could use

```
(dec (count dummyvector))
```

or

```
(->> dummyvector count dec)
```

or if you *really* want to go the long way around the barn to find this

```
(last (keys (zipmap (range 1 (count dummyvector)) dummyvector)))
```

Comment: Use the last example if you want to be passive aggressive.